# One or more validation errors were detected during model generation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity, entity-framework-6

I have a problem when selecting a User.

```
  public class UserMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
  {
    public UserMap ()
    {
        ToTable("USERS");
        HasKey(e => e.Id);
        Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("ID");
        Property(e => e.Name).HasColumnName("NAME");
        Property(e => e.Password).HasColumnName("PASSWORD");
        Property(e => e.Date).HasColumnName("DATE");
        Property(e => e.Token).HasColumnName("TOKEN");
        Property(e => e.Active).HasColumnName("ACTIVE");

        HasRequired(e => e.Company).WithMany().Map(e => e.MapKey("COMPANY_ID"));
        HasMany(e => e.BranchesUsers).WithRequired().Map(e => e.MapKey("USER_ID"));
    }
  }

public class BranchMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Branch>
{
    public BranchMap ()
    {
        ToTable("BRANCHES");
        HasKey(e => e.Id);
        Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("ID");
        Property(e => e.Name).HasColumnName("NAME");
        Property(e => e.Date).HasColumnName("DATE");
        Property(e => e.Active).HasColumnName("ACTIVE");

        HasRequired(e => e.Company).WithMany().Map(e => e.MapKey("COMPANY_ID"));
        HasMany(e => e.UsersBranches).WithRequired().Map(e => e.MapKey("BRANCH_ID"));
    }
}

public class UserBranchMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<UserBranch>
{
    public UserBranchMap()
    {
        ToTable("USERS_BRANCHES");
        HasKey(e => e.Id);
        Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("ID");

        HasOptional(e => e.User).WithMany().Map(e => e.MapKey("USER_ID"));
        HasOptional(e => e.Profile).WithMany().Map(e => e.MapKey("PROFILE_ID"));
        HasOptional(e => e.Branch).WithMany().Map(e => e.MapKey("BRANCH_ID"));
        HasOptional(e => e.Company).WithMany().Map(e => e.MapKey("COMPANY_ID"));
    }
}
```

this is my model:

```
   public class User
   {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public List<UserBranch> BranchesUsers{ get; set; }
    public bool Active{ get; set; }
   }

public class Branch
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public Company Company{ get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public List<UserBranch> UsersBranches { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}

   public class UserBranch
   {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public Profile Profile { get; set; }
    public Branch Branch { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
   }
```

when I perform a simple select the user model I get this error:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> USER_ID: Name: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'USER_ID' is already defined.
>
> BRANCH_ID: Name: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'BRANCH_ID' is already defined.

Comment: UserBranch has a Branch property. However, you are telling EF to not use this navigation property in the relationship Branch<-> UserBranch. so, now EF still has to map the Branch Navigation property to a foreign key, which fails because it is already there. You should use the overload WithRequired(x=>x.Branch) to avoid this issue.

Comment: Now he throw this: The navigation property 'User' declared on type 'UserBranch' has been configured with conflicting multiplicities.

Comment: Did you configure User with inverse navigation property as well? Also: you don't need to configure both directions, you could skip the configuration of navigation properties in user and Branch.